# i am trying to read the first bytes of an Elf file

Tags: c, io, elf

I am writing C code to read the first 4 bytes of an ELF file and compare it with 0x7f to see if i get a match but it doesn't seem to be working. what am i doing wrong?

```
#include "main.h"
/**
 * readFirst4 - function to read first eight bytes
 * @filename: filename of file to be read
 * Return: string of bytes to be checked
 */
char *readFirst4(int fd_elf)
{
        unsigned int _read1;
        char *test_string;

        _read1 = read(fd_elf, test_string, sizeof(int));
        if (_read1 != 0 && _read1 != -1)
                return (test_string);
        else
                return ("Error unable to read file\n");
}

/**
 * closeFile - function that closes a file
 * @fd_elf: file descriptor
 */
void closeFile(int fd_elf, char *filename)
{
        if((close(fd_elf) == -1))
        {
                dprintf(STDERR_FILENO, "Error: unable to close file %s\n", filename);
                exit(98);
        }
}

/**
 * main - execute program
 * @argc: number of arguments
 * @args: array of arguments
 * Return: 0
 */
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
        int fd_ELF, reader;
        char *first_four;

        first_four = malloc(sizeof(int));
        if (first_four == NULL)
                exit(98);

        if (argc != 2)
        {
                dprintf(STDERR_FILENO, "Usage: elf_header filename\n");
                exit(98);
        }

        fd_ELF = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
        if (fd_ELF == -1)
        {
                dprintf(STDERR_FILENO, "Error unable to read file %s\n", argv[1]);
                exit(98);
        }
        if ((first_four = readFirst4(fd_ELF)) != (char *)0x7F)
        {
                printf("%s\n", first_four);
                dprintf(STDERR_FILENO, "Error: Not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start\n");
                exit(98);
        }
        printf("file %s is an ELF file", argv[1]);
        closeFile(fd_ELF, argv[1]);
        return (0);
}
```

from my code the error message is only supposed to display if the file is not an elf file.

i included the printf before the error to see the bytes read. I keep getting a ? symbol inside a box and then the error message because the bytes read don't match 0x7f which is the first bytes of an elf

Comment: `test_string` is not pointing to any valid memory.

Comment: `if ((first_four = readFirst4(fd_ELF)) != (char *)0x7F)` compares the _pointer_ `first_four` with 0x7F (quite unlikely to be the pointer value) and not the content

Comment: btw: `sizeof(int)` is not necessarily 4. If you want to read exactly four bytes, pass `4` to `read()`. And `read` does *not* return an unsigned value

Comment: Aside: the use of leading underscores in identifiers is reserved - don't use them.

Comment: To read an `int`: `int x; ssize_t result = read(fd, &x, sizeof(x) );`  All your code with pointers is just taking something simple and making it overly complex and confusing.

Comment: @AndrewHenle the first four bytes of an ELF file are 0x7f + "ELF". I would'nt try to read them as an int

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt True, a `uint32_t` would be portable as the size would be correct, while an `int` might not be.  Of course the `uint32_t` value might then have to be converted from the big-endian value in the file to the proper host endianness - or endianness otherwise accounted for - when checking the value.  ;-)  (Yeah, I wouldn't try ti identify an ELF file that way, either, but the question **is** about reading it as an `int`...)

Comment: what's the best way to try reading it then?

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation look really convoluted. Try using the structure below.

```
int main(int argc, const char ** argv) {
  // program argument checks

  // open file
  int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
  // file discriptor checks
  char ref[4] = {0x7f, 0x45, 0x4c, 0x46};
  char arr[4];
  int cnt = read(fd, (char*) &arr, sizeof(char) * 4);
  // read check
  // expected values in arr is 0x7f 0x45 0x4c 0x46
  int cmp = memcmp((char*)&arr, (char*)&ret, 4 * sizeof(char));
  if(cmp == 0) {
    // ELF file found
  }
  close(fd);
  return 0;
}
```